# Count unique characters and list the current count at each line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

```
a
b
b
c
c
c
```

I was looking for a way (using linux command) to convert the above text file into something below:

```
a 1  
b 1
b 2
c 1
c 2
c 3
```

Basically, read from the first line and count the occurrence of a unique  character up to a certain line and list the current occurrence of the unique character to that line. In the case above, "a", "b" and "c" are unique characters and the occurrence of a unique character (eg, "c") starts from 1 to the total occurrence of "c".

Comment: To your given input / desired output the answer is quite straight forward. Better post a [mcve] with what you are really looking for, specially since the last paragraph makes me think the requirement is broader.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of how many times they appeared so far:

```
$ awk '{print $1, ++a[$1]}' file
a 1
b 1
b 2
c 1
c 2
c 3
```

Comment: Thanks. It's quite helpful.